# Track video using X-API or Tin-Can-API

Tags: youtube, scorm, tin-can-api

I am developing a learning content and I want to track the learner activities using Tin-Can API or X-API.

Is it possible to track the video content (YouTube videos added in my course page) ?
Tracking the content like learner started the video, Completed the Video, Resume from 1:30 min. Something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely possible! You can use YouTube's bespoke API and translate this into standardised Tin Can data.

See [this blog](http://tincanapi.com/2013/08/27/youtube-tin-can-amazing/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=blog&utm_campaign=youtube_tincan?pmc=em-1) and [this blog](http://tincanapi.com/2013/08/28/youtubetin-can-tech-tips/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=blog&utm_campaign=youtube_tincan_tech?pmc=em-1) for more details. Be sure to read the comments as there's helpful stuff in there too!

Answer (score 2):

As well as the blog posts Andrew mentioned you may also be interested in the Video Profile + Recipe available at:

https://registry.tincanapi.com/#profile/19

And in particular our code library and sample website that connects to YouTube's API and uses the Recipe's spec for tracking using statements. That code is available at:

https://github.com/RusticiSoftware/TinCanRecipes

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get into coding you can use GrassBlade xAPI Companion plugin with WordPress:
http://www.nextsoftwaresolutions.com/grassblade-xapi-companion/

You will also need an LRS like GrassBlade LRS

If Videos are important to you, you might want to participate in Video Community of Practice that is working on defining video tracking standard of Tin Can API.
https://github.com/liveaspankaj/xapi-video-cop/wiki